# I can't get automatic unit testing to work with Jenkins and Sonar (and finally with Maven)

Tags: unit-testing, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, tycho

I don't know if I understand something wrong. I' trying to get automatic unit testing to work in my project.

I made a Eclipse Plugin Project and converted it into a Maven Project. I made a JUnit test case class testing the only class in the project. I placed every code in the Maven way (i.e. src/main/java main code and src/test/java test code).

I placed the test class in src/test/java in a package called pluginmaventest.actions .

The test case automatically fails if started in Eclipse as a JUnit test.

I shared the project in a SVN repository and made a Jenkins job (Maven 2/3 project). I added the JUnit dependency to the pom.xml and all necessary tycho dependencies.

The project build is successful. Shouldn't it be failing because my JUnit test fails?

I tried

```
mvn clean install
```

and

```
mvn test
```

as goals. I even tried to use `-Dtest=SomeClassTest`. The build never fails.

This obviously means that the unit test is neither compiled nor performed, doesn't it?

I'm just trying to get a grip with Jenkins, Sonar and unit tests. My momentary goal is to get unit tests running with Jenkins, and then try to get code analysis and test coverage running with Sonar, which is integrated into Jenkins. Is there a comprehensive and understandable tutorial or how-to on the web?

ADDENDUM:

- My Jenkins installation can produce failing builds, so that should not be the problem.
- My test class is really named SomeClassTest. Oh, oers already edited that.
- Local Maven calls of the test goal produce no results, either.

Here is my whole project pom.xml. (without surefire maven didn't produce any output, either)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/
XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://
maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>test.maven.plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>pluginmaventest</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Bla</name>
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

<properties>
    <tycho-version>0.13.0</tycho-version>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>indigo</id>
      <layout>p2</layout>
      <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho-version}</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.11</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho-version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho-version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <resolver>p2</resolver>
            <environments>
                <environment>
                    <os>linux</os>
                    <ws>gtk</ws>
                    <arch>x86</arch>
                </environment>
                <environment>
                    <os>linux</os>
                    <ws>gtk</ws>
                    <arch>x86_64</arch>
                </environment>
                <environment>
                    <os>win32</os>
                    <ws>win32</ws>
                    <arch>x86</arch>
                </environment>
                <environment>
                    <os>win32</os>
                    <ws>win32</ws>
                    <arch>x86_64</arch>
                </environment>
                <environment>
                    <os>macosx</os>
                    <ws>cocoa</ws>
                    <arch>x86_64</arch>
                </environment>
            </environments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: It sounds like an error in your pom.xml.  If it's not giant, could you include that in your question? Also, can you specify the full path to your test class (including the name of the file)?

Comment: In which location did you put your Test class ?

Comment: In src/test/java in a package called pluginmaventest.actions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check your project setup against the working demo example with tests:
http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.git/tree/tycho-demo/itp01

Comment: Wait, so I can't use the Maven conventional project layout with an Eclipse Plugin Project? I can't have main sources and test sources together in a project? I have to have a separate project?

Comment: And do I have to have a parent project containing the modules?

Comment: Okay, the examples helped making unit testing work. People, make separate bundles for sources and testing (use Fragment Project for test bundles). Make a parent pom describing the submodules and voilá, it works.

Comment: Maybe you can explain why this is the answer, I am failing to understand why because it's just a link, I'm sure others would feel the same.

Comment: Well, the better link would be https://github.com/jsievers/tycho-demo/tree/master/exercises/ .I read the exercises in this tycho tutorial, reproduced the projects on my own pc, and got everything to work. The link has a tutorial for creating a plugin project, adding unit tests and more.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that the build runs the tests locally when you build with maven.  If that is the case, then it could be that Jenkins isn't getting the updates from SVN.  Configure it to checkout rather than update for the build and see if it now runs the tests.  If that doesn't cause the failure (or at least cause the tests to run) then have a look at the console output from the Jenkins build and see what clues are in there for your build.

Comment: Nothing happens if i locally (with m2eclipse) run the test goal,too. What would you need me to post to diagnose why this happens?

Comment: try it outside of eclipse.  command line.  Also, are your tests written correctly?  Do they have the appropriate annotations or whatever so maven knows they are tests?  i.e. @Test

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins should mark the build as UNSTABLE (yellow ball) if a test fails. Most people consider this superior to a FAILED status (red ball) because it provides more information.  You ought to be able to see a graph of test passes/failures for all jobs on the job detail page.

If you would like to see what a failure looks like (say you want a sanity check), you could try committing uncompilable code, or calling invalid Maven goals.

Comment: I've seen builds failing on our Jenkins, so that should not be the problem. Thanks for the info about the yellow ball.

Comment: Using tycho, no yellow ball seems to be available, as the tycho-surefire-plugin tells that tests failed, but tells of a whole build failure.